# SqlKata: SELECT STUFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, for-xml-path, sqlkata

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server and I would like to transfer it to C# code using sqlKata.

I was able to do most of the transcripts but I am having trouble with one fragment.

It is my SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_procedure] 
    @UserId INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        STUFF((SELECT InboxHtml AS [text()]
               FROM [dbo].[my_procedure] WITH (NOLOCK)
               WHERE UserId = @UserId
                 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), VisibleUntil) > 0
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 0, NULL) AS InboxHtml 
END
```

And in C# with sqlkata:

```
db.Query("my_procedure").Select("InboxHtml").Where(new { UserId = id })
                .WhereRaw("DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), VisibleUntil) > ?", 0)
```

How can I add `STUFF ... FOR XML PATH` with sqlKata??

Thanks ! :)

Comment: `FOR XML PATH('')` is a way of abusing SQL Server's XML support with a trick that ends up concatenating strings together. Since you're loading this data into C# which has *far more powerful* string processing functionality, why continue to use the `FOR XML` trick?

Comment: As to the `STUFF` use here, that's definitely someone using something without understanding it. The arguments to `STUFF` here are `<the string concatenated via XML>, 1, 0, NULL` - now, go and read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) for length and replacewith